# JavaScript framekiller and XSS vulnerability

Tags: javascript, iframe, xss

Are all [known](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framekiller) [javascript framekillers](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/break-out-of-iframe/) vulnerable to XSS?

If yes, whould it be enough to sanitize `window.location` before breaking out of an iframe? 
What would be the best way to do it? 
Could you please give an example of possible XSS attack?

Thanks!

**UPD:** The reason I'm asking is because I got a vulnerability scan alert saying that JS framekiller code containing `top.location.replace(document.location)` is XSS vulnerable as `document.location` is controlled by the user.

Comment: Why do you think any have XSS issues? Frame-busters aren't typically related to XSS at all, they're intended to deal with spoofing and clickjacking.

Comment: Are you asking for code to avoid framekillers? JS-based solutions which are loaded within the frame can also be accessed, modified and therefore get tricked, yes.

Comment: @JeremyBanks I have updated the question to clarify the reason why I'm asking this

Comment: @Smamatti nope, I'm not looking for a killer of framekiller. Please see my update

Comment: What you are talking about has nothing to do with XSS. They can't run code in your frame without you allowing it because of the same origin policy anyway.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, then what can I change to kill off that vulnerability scan alert?

Comment: " I got a vulnerability scan alert " from what tool?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum http://www.alertlogic.com/solutions/security/vulnerability-assessment/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What was right in their description: variables like '*document.location*', '*window.location*', '*self.location*' are (partially) controlled by non-trusted user. This is because the choice of (sub)string in non-trusted domain and page location ('http://**non.trusted.domain**.com/**mypage**') and non-trusted request string ('http://my.domain.com/?**myrequest**') are formed according to user's intention that may not always be good for you.

What was wrong: this user-dependency is not necessarily XSS vulnerability. In fact, to form XSS you would need to have some code that effectively *uses* the content controlled by non-trusted user somewhere in your output stream for your page. In the example of simple framekiller like `top.location.replace(window.location)` there's no danger of XSS.

One example where we could talk about XSS would be code like

`document.write('<a href="' + document.location + '?newvar=newvalue">Click here</a>')`

Constructing URI like `http://test.com/?dummy"<script>alert("Test")</script>"dummy` and substituting instead of *document.location* by you code will trigger non-trusted script in trusted webpage's context. As constructing such URI and passing it unescaped is a challenge, real XSS would work in some more complex scenarios involving inserting non-trusted variables verbatim into flow of language directives, be it HTML, CSS, JS, PHP, etc.

Another well-known example of XSS-unaware development was history of inventing [JSON](http://www.json.org). While JSON has got strong popularity (having me among its proponents too), initially it was intended as "quick-n-dirty" way of storing JS data as pieces of plain JS-formatted data structures. In order to "parse" JSON blocks, it was enough just to *eval()* them. Fortunately, people quickly recognised how flawed was this whole idea, so nowadays any knowledgeable developer in sane mind will always use proper safe JSON parser instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a detailed answer! Now that I have confirmation of framekiller code safety, the only question which remains is what can I do to prevent that scan alert...

Comment: I reformatted my answer to show correct code as SO ate `<script>` tags. Do you have any concrete code receiving the alert or are you just looking for some framekiller not producing it? What code have you tried so far? One more thought about adapting you code to please AlertLogic is you potentially may introduce real XSS upon making it more complex in order to avoid the warning. So, do weigh your real needs between *showing* you're free from XSS and *being* free from XSS.

Comment: Yes, I have concrete code and it is as simple as `if (parent.frames.length > 0) top.location.replace(document.location);` And I do understand that I may introduce a real XSS by trying to make it more complex. And at the same time there is no assurance that more complex code won't cause scan alert